# Can we call a sleep() method using subclass object in java?

Tags: multithreading

Usually we call a sleep method of thread using

Thread.sleep(2000);

But can we call that method using subclass object of Thread class ?

Can any one clarify this doubt ?

Comment: The answer is simple. Can you call static method of parent class using Child Class reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that the method sleep(int) of Thread is static. So, you'll be able to call it on a subclass in the same way if you do not redefine it in your subclass.

The given code calls the sleep method of Thread.

A subclass of Thread

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {}
```

The main function

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        MyThread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```